# Cron job to put files on server

Tags: php, perl, cgi, cron

Let me start by saying that I know nothing about Cron, so sorry.  How can I make a php or perl script get files from my computer and upload them to my web server everyday at midnight?

The webserver is linux.  The computer from which the files need to be retrieved is Windows.

Comment: Please add more info about your computer. What is it running, WIndows or Linux?

Comment: (1) Write a script to upload files from your computer to your web server (2) Learn about cron [it's not that hard. And with cygwin or mingw you can use it on Windows] (3) Use cron to run the script every day at midnight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron will start a script or run a command on the local computer (the computer running cron) at regular intervals. If you can run a script on your computer that will upload files to your webserver, then cron can schedule that script to run at midnight every night. (Assuming you're running an operating system that has cron or something cron-like.) Cron will not, however, help you write the script to upload the files.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to put an FTP server on your server and use the FTP functions PHP has to upload (using FTP ofcourse) from your computer to the server.
I assume it is obvious there are "some" security issues with approach you should take extra care to handle.

Comment: @Christopher "One cow at a time, and we'll eat the entire herd" 
Did you install FTP server on the machine you wish to upload to files?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Linux, the below commands will show you the relevant manual pages:

```
man cron      # man page for cron
man 1 crontab # man page for "crontab" program that installs and edits crontabs
man 5 crontab # man page for cron schedule files (called "crontabs")
```

Basically, cron runs commands from a schedule.  The schedule is called a "crontab", and the command that installs and edits them is also called a "crontab".  You could use

```
crontab -e
```

to edit your crontab in an editor.  Or you could create a crontab file and then just install it using

```
crontab file_to_use_as_crontab
```

To see your current crontab, use

```
crontab -l
```

The crontab file format can be cryptic.  The below example crontab executes /fully/qualified/path/to/script_that_copies_files every day at midnight.  Fully qualifying the path to your script is recommended.

```
# minute hour day month dayofweek
0 0 * * * /fully/qualified/path/to/script_that_copies_files
```

Comment: I think the main doubt was surrounding the upload of a file, and not really how to execute a cron job.

Comment: @IvoPereira I went by the first sentence of the post, "Let me start by saying that I know nothing about Cron, so sorry.".